# What does p(x, z) mean in probabilities?

Tags: probability, distributions, bayesian, autoencoders

I'm trying to understand variational autoencoders, and it is not as straightforward as I thought - not knowing much about probability theories.

It is related with the Bayes theorem that I learnt from [this amazing tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HZGCoVF3YvM). However, the example in the video to make people understand the concept, and using it in context of VAE is kind of a different level.

The equation that explains the encoder looks like this:
$$p_\theta(x,z) = p_\theta(x|z)p(z)$$

Where $p_\theta(x|z)$ is the likelihood, what is the probability of $x$ is true given $z$ is true.

$p(z)$ is the prior, what is the probability of $z$ is true in general.

But what is $p(x, z)$? Is it a function with two parameters $x$, and $z$? Or is like the case of $p(z)$, just with knowing not just $z$, but $x$ as well, and the probability of both events are true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The video you linked focuses on probability distributions where the hypothesis is binary; i.e. $H$ is a random variable with two possible values of "true" or "false". For Variational Autoencoders, we're typically interested in much richer random variables.

For example, VAEs are commonly used for images. In this setting, $x$ is a random variable over matrices of pixel values, and it does not make sense to talk about it being "true" or "false". Similarly, $z$, often called the *code*, is a random variable over vectors, not "true" or "false".

$p(z)$ is a [*probability density*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function) over possible code vectors $z$: i.e., $p(z) \geq 0$ for all $z$, and $\int p(z) dz = 1$. Similarly, $p(x|z)$ is a probability density over possible matrices of pixel values $x$ for a particular $z$: $p(x|z) \geq 0$ for all $x$, and $\int p(x | z) dx = 1$.

$p(x, z)$ is then a joint density over both images and codes: $p(x, z)$ will be larger for $x$ and $z$ that are more likely, smaller (but not negative) for $x$ and $z$ that are less likely, and $\int \int p(x, z) dx dz = 1$.

Note that $p(z)$ is not the probability that $z$ takes a particular value. For continuous random variables, we can get the probability that the variable falls in a range of possible values, but the probability that it takes any single value is zero.

Answer (score 2):

$p_\theta(x,z)$ is simply the probability that $x$ and $z$ are both true

Comment: Can we say that $p(x, z)$ is the same as $p(z|x)$?

Comment: @GergőHorváth No as it is smaller unless $p(x)=1$.  The next step is $p(x,z)=p(z \mid x)p(x)$ and so Bayes' theorem $p(z \mid x) = \dfrac{p(x \mid z)p(z)}{p(x)}$ at least when $p(x)>0$

Comment: Might be that the functions  $p()$ refer to densities, in which case $p(x,z)$ is not the probability anymore, but the joint PDF. Then the integral over $p()$ is the probability.

Comment: @PaulG.  Possibly, except that the original question says " the probability of $x$ is true given $z$ is true" which suggests events rather than random variables